# Deriving the formula for derangements: $\text{Round}\left[\frac{n!}{e}\right]$

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I saw on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) that a formula for derangements is

$\text{Round}\left[\frac{n!}{e}\right]$

However, how did they arrive at this elegant formula?

Does it have to do with $ !n=n! \sum _{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$

Comment: Please add the link to go to the page of Wikipeadia

Comment: Yes, the formula on the last line is where this comes from.

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!}< e^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!}<\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!}$

Therefor, we have that identity.